# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool on line 83

Tags: php, wordpress

Just noticed this after turning on debug mode in Php 7.4. There are a few questions out there in relation, but none of have an up-voted answer. Would love to have a decent answer for those who will also be reaching the same problem in 7.4 WP

These lines read:

```
   // Get image size after cropping.
            $dims = image_resize_dimensions( $orig_w, $orig_h, $width, $height, $crop );
            $dst_w = $dims[4];
            $dst_h = $dims[5];

            // Return the original image only if it exactly fits the needed measures.
            if ( ! $dims && ( ( ( null === $height && $orig_w == $width ) xor ( null === $width && $orig_h == $height ) ) xor ( $height == $orig_h && $width == $orig_w ) ) ) {
                $img_url = $url;
                $dst_w = $orig_w;
                $dst_h = $orig_h;
            } else {
                // Use this to check if cropped image already exists, so we can return that instead.
                $suffix = "{$dst_w}x{$dst_h}";
                $dst_rel_path = str_replace( '.' . $ext, '', $rel_path );
                $destfilename = "{$upload_dir}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";

                if ( ! $dims || ( true == $crop && false == $upscale && ( $dst_w < $width || $dst_h < $height ) ) ) {
                    // Can't resize, so return false saying that the action to do could not be processed as planned.
                    return false;
                }
                // Else check if cache exists.
                elseif ( file_exists( $destfilename ) && getimagesize( $destfilename ) ) {
                    $img_url = "{$upload_url}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
                }
                // Else, we resize the image and return the new resized image url.
                else {

                    $editor = wp_get_image_editor( $img_path );

                    if ( is_wp_error( $editor ) || is_wp_error( $editor->resize( $width, $height, $crop ) ) )
                        return false;

                    $resized_file = $editor->save();

                    if ( ! is_wp_error( $resized_file ) ) {
                        $resized_rel_path = str_replace( $upload_dir, '', $resized_file['path'] );
                        $img_url = $upload_url . $resized_rel_path;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
```

**The Resolved Code is as follows:** - As mentioned in the approved answer's comment, the declaratives $dst_w & dst_h have been placed into the else statement.

```
 // Get image size after cropping.
            $dims = image_resize_dimensions( $orig_w, $orig_h, $width, $height, $crop );

            // Return the original image only if it exactly fits the needed measures.
            if ( ! $dims && ( ( ( null === $height && $orig_w == $width ) xor ( null === $width && $orig_h == $height ) ) xor ( $height == $orig_h && $width == $orig_w ) ) ) {
                $img_url = $url;
                $dst_w = $orig_w;
                $dst_h = $orig_h;
            } else {
                // Use this to check if cropped image already exists, so we can return that instead.
                $suffix = "{$dst_w}x{$dst_h}";
                $dst_rel_path = str_replace( '.' . $ext, '', $rel_path );
                $destfilename = "{$upload_dir}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
            $dst_w = $dims[4];
            $dst_h = $dims[5];

                if ( ! $dims || ( true == $crop && false == $upscale && ( $dst_w < $width || $dst_h < $height ) ) ) {
                    // Can't resize, so return false saying that the action to do could not be processed as planned.
                    return false;
                }
                // Else check if cache exists.
                elseif ( file_exists( $destfilename ) && getimagesize( $destfilename ) ) {
                    $img_url = "{$upload_url}{$dst_rel_path}-{$suffix}.{$ext}";
                }
                // Else, we resize the image and return the new resized image url.
                else {

                    $editor = wp_get_image_editor( $img_path );

                    if ( is_wp_error( $editor ) || is_wp_error( $editor->resize( $width, $height, $crop ) ) )
                        return false;

                    $resized_file = $editor->save();

                    if ( ! is_wp_error( $resized_file ) ) {
                        $resized_rel_path = str_replace( $upload_dir, '', $resized_file['path'] );
                        $img_url = $upload_url . $resized_rel_path;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notice means that $dims is not an array but a boolean, probably because image_resize_dimensions fails and returns false.

image_resize_dimensions returns false if

- the original size is 0 or less
- both destination with and height are 0/not specified
- the original size is equal to the destination size (in which case the image does not need to be resized)

You should check that $dims is not false before trying to access $dims[4] and $dims[5].

Comment: That is what I was thinking. But then would this mean that the resolution requires me to alter all locations in which $dims is called? Or is there a resolution that we can insert right here? Also, how did 7.4 bring about this Notice as it lied dormant in all previous versions

Comment: I would assume that warnings just were not logged before. Your code works fine. Your if statement checks if !$dims ($dims === false) and  just uses the original size as the destination size. You just need to move the $dst_w = $dims[4]; $dst_h = $dims[5]; part inside the else body so that it is not executed if $dims is not an array.

Comment: I also assume I was over analyzing. This was more of a curiosity and I did see other unanswered questions in this regard; so thank you!